# Python built-in module for handling Excel files

Tags: python, excel, csv, python-module, built-in

I know similar questions have been popular in the past, but none refers to my problem. I'm looking for a way to read data from Excel file in Python, but I'm strongly against using non-builtin modules.

The reason why is that in my case Python is a component of [another software](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/), so incorporating additional module would require from every user knowledge about how to use `pip`, which Python installation on your pc should one install module into, etc. The solution must not require any additional actions from user.

I can read CSV files with Python builtin easily, so that could work, but how can I convert Excel to CSV in the first place? Or is there a way to read Excel directly?

Edit: It is Python 2, that is used in this software.

Edit2: 
Anyone minds explaining the downvote? I think this isn't a question about a ready solution or module, but rather a method and is well detailed. It is not always possible to use external modules, so this is an actual problem. If it is not possible at all though, then I would simply expect an answer instead of -1.

Comment: It may not be realistic to expect to be able to read an excel file without using any extra modules.

Comment: I don't think there's a native python modules to interact with Excel. Saving an Excel to CSV should be easy: File -> Save As -> Choose CSV in the File Format dropdown (note you'll lose coloring information, etc.)

Comment: *"how can I convert Excel to CSV"* isn't a programming question, that's built right into Excel. If you want to know what's in the standard library, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/

Comment: Thanks everyone. Yes, I expect there is no pretty solution, I'm just hoping for some (maybe long, not so efficient, inelegant compared to pandas etc) workaround.

Comment: The user is never responsible to install anything, you should write the installation in your code if the appplied package is not installed yet. The platform needs network connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really the prettiest solution, but you could download the complete code repository of one of the excel handling packages for python ([`openpyxl`](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/downloads/) for example) and put these files in the same directory as the python script that you're going to run. Subsequently you can do an `import` of these local package files in your script.

Note: if the excel handling package has dependencies on other packages, then you'll need to download these as well.

Comment: I couldn't find any better solution. Thank you. Important note - when doing this, take a look at the license of taken package.

Comment: If all you are going to do is read, I strongly recommend using `xlrd` instead.

Comment: @JohnY For which reason exactly?

Comment: I find xlrd has a better API. I trust it to [preserve data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637888/openpyxl-please-do-not-assume-text-as-a-number-when-importing) more than I trust OpenPyXL. xlrd reads both .xls and .xlsx. xlrd doesn't have any other dependencies (last time I looked, OpenPyXL does).

Comment: After some time, I'll add to this that when you "embed" library's code into your package, you have to maintain it as well, for example track any potential security issues and update the embedded package accordingly.

Comment: cannot even visit the URL you provided and cannot download xlrd package myself. So, no support for excel by python without a 3rd party library support?

Comment: OpenPyXL has dependencies. which can be problematic. especially when the install area is maintained by another person (aka, IT ) and you don't have control over it. ( future code failure if things change )